# Calculate days between Start and End date at an offset

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have created a Calendar Table in SQL with these columns:

[image]

Now I have a start date, end date and an offset, and have to calculate days as explained below:

```
start date: 1-12-2016----End date: 10-12-2016----Offset: 2
```

Output:

```
1-12-2016
3-12-2016
5-12-2016
7-12-2016
9-12-2016
```

I cant seem to be able to think a query for this. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use modulo arithmetic:

```
select c.date
from calendar c
where c.date >= @startdate and
      c.date <= @enddate and
      datediff(day, @startdate, c.date) % @offset = 0
```

Comment: I like this one

Answer (score 0):

You might use a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER()` in connection with `modulo -> %`

### EDIT: Changed this to fit better to your needs

Try the following code:

```
DECLARE @Offset INT=3;
DECLARE @start DATE={d'2016-12-01'};
DECLARE @end DATE={d'2016-12-10'};

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.DateKey)  AS Nr
    FROM YourTable AS t
    WHERE t.Date>=@start AND t.Date<=@end
)
SELECT *
FROM Numbered
WHERE (Nr % @Offset)=1
```

Comment: . . I didn't downvote, but your query doesn't return dates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, well, I had not fun typing in a test table so I showed the principles... The OP should have no problem, to transfer this approach to the given scenario... Maybe I was to lazy :-)